# Lodash forEach function omit

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an object in my `.js` file (node)

```
var z = [
    {'a': 'uno', 'b': 'dos'},
    {'a': 'uno', 'b': 'dos'},
    {'a': 'uno', 'b': 'dos'},
    {'a': 'uno', 'b': 'dos'}
];
```

I would like to omit each `'a'` from `z` object.

I'm trying with something like this, but is not working.

```
var y = _.forEach(z, function(n){
    //console.log(_.omit(n, 'a'));
    return _.omit(n, 'a');
});

console.log(y);
```

I tried without return, and few ways more, but didn't get it.

My jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/baumannzone/jzs6n78m/

Any help? Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new array of objects, by omitting `a` from each of them

```
console.log(_.map(z, function (obj) {
  return _.omit(obj, 'a');
}));
// [ { b: 'dos' }, { b: 'dos' }, { b: 'dos' }, { b: 'dos' } ]
```

As it is, you are omitting and creating a new object but that object is ignored by `_.each`. Now, we use `_.map`, which will gather all the values returned from the function and form a new array.

---

If you prefer a one-liner, create a partial function and leave only the object to be used as `_`, like this

```
console.log(_.map(z, _.partial(_.omit, _, 'a')));
// [ { b: 'dos' }, { b: 'dos' }, { b: 'dos' }, { b: 'dos' } ]
```

Comment: Thanks you both! Then, when is usefull to use `_.forEach`?

Comment: @JorgeBaumann When you are doing something which has side effects.

Answer (score 3):

```
var y = _.map(z, function(n) {
    return _.omit(n, 'a');
});
```

This will create a new array from the old one, mapping the objects in z to new objects that omit the 'a' attribute.

An alternative is to use chaining, so:

```
var y = _(z).map(function(n){return n.omit('a');}).value();
```

B

Comment: The other answer is better, tick that :)